# Runtime-Analysis for single loop incremented by a factor of 3

Tags: runtime-analysis, loops

So, I'm trying to understand how to  get the run time of this loop:

```c
for(int i = 1; i < n*n*n; i*=3) {...}
```

So, far I know:

- loop starts at 1
- finishes when $i  > n^3-1$
- that $i$ is multiplied by 3 each iteration.

Intuitively it seems like as $n$ gets larger the number of iterations decreases which makes me think that the run-time is $O(log$ $n)$. My question is if this is correct if it is what is a mathematical way I could derive that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. This for loop stops when: 
$$
3^i < n^3 \rightarrow i<3\log(n)
$$
Which implies the complexity of this for loop is $O(\log(n))$.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on how you reached that conclusion?